# MySQL/MariaDB replication encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, database-replication, mariadb

How can I configure encryption between my MYSQL/MariaDB servers which use replication without using SSL?

I'd don't want to use SSL since I'd have to buy certificates for all my servers and because the certificates expire..

Isn't it possible to set a password that is used for the encryption?

Comment: If these are just internal servers, you can generate your own SSL certificates and install your CA certificate in the trust root. It would be just as secure as buying a certificate (assuming you protect the private key), and safer than using passwords. You can set the expiration to years out, so renewal wouldn't be a problem either.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to buy SSL certificates for your MySQL servers.  You can generate them yourself for free.  I've never seen it done any other way with MySQL.

You also don't have to have short expiration times (although good security practice suggests that the certificates be periodically rotated)... you can specify the expiration time of your certificates when you create them, many years into the future, if desired.

This is all in the documentation.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-ssl-certs.html

Also... No, you can't encrypt replication with a password.

Alternately, you could tunnel between the servers using SSH, but that is more complicated, not built-in, and more failure-prone that doing it the standard way, with native SSL.